# Presenting UIActivityViewController initiating from inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiactivityviewcontroller

Below code work fine and presents `UIActivityViewController` when put inside `PostsVC` (Mian View Controller) but gives ***cell does not have a member named 'presentViewController'*** error when put inside tap action of a UIButton which is placed inside UITableViewCell on the same PostsVC view controller.

How do I reference to PostsVC in the last line of code to present it ?

```
let appAddress =  "https://itunes.apple.com/app/id978654?ls=1&mt=8"
let shareText = "Share our app "
let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText, appAddress], applicationActivities: nil)
self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a weak reference to your view controller in your cell subclass. Set this in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.viewController = self
```

Then call the presentViewController method on cell.viewController rather than the cell itself.

Comment: Error on line `cell.viewController = self` 'cell' does not have a member named 'viewController'

Comment: @Kashif yes, you'll have to add a property for that in your cell subclass

Comment: For someone else reading, you have to do `weak var parentViewController = UIViewController()` in your cell subclass